# Wrong return value uint256

Tags: solidity

this contract not returns a correct value, what's wrong? The MASK don't seems correct,`shiftedGroupId` not returns anything

```
 // SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
    
    pragma solidity 0.7.6;
    
    /**
     * @title Storage
     * @dev Store & retrieve value in a variable
     */
    contract Storage {
    
    
          uint256 public constant GROUP_MASK = uint256(uint128(~0)) << 128;
    
        /**
         * @dev Store value in variable
         * @param id value to store
         */
        function store(uint256 id)  public view returns (uint256){
            
             uint256 shiftedGroupId = (id & GROUP_MASK);
            uint256 groupId = shiftedGroupId >> 128;
            
            return groupId;
          
        }
 
    }
```

Comment: store function with id = 1 returns 0

Comment: Please try to be more clear. What's your desired outcome? Provide some examples on what's the input and the expected output and what you're getting instead with this code.

Comment: I want to pass id=1 from javascript contract instace to this contract and the value must be 1

Comment: If you want to receive exactly what you sent then don't use the mask...

Answer (score 1):

```
uint256 shiftedGroupId = (id & GROUP_MASK);
```

When the `id` is `1`, this line assigns to the `shiftedGroupId` the value of

```
1 & 115792089237316195423570985008687907852929702298719625575994209400481361428480
```

*(one ampersand is the "bitwise and" operator)*

Which is `0`.

And when you shift `0` by 128 bytes (and assign to the `groupId`), it's still `0`.

Comment: I want to pass id=1 from javascript contract instace to this contract and the value must be 1

Answer (score 0):

```
contract Storage {
        /**
         * @dev Store value in variable
         * @param id value to store
         */
        uint256 id;
        function store(uint256 _id) public {
               id = _id;
        }
}
```

This is a contract that recieves something and stores it in the blockchain. I don't understand what's up with the mask. Please explain further if you insist on using that mask.